# Installshield 2011 - Problem Upgrading existing software with Version format 2009.727.1365

Tags: installshield

Using Installshield 2011, we're creating a major upgrade and having problems upgrading software with this Product Version format - 2009.727.1365.  We keep getting the standard 'Installed software is newer than product to be installed' message.  With IS 2011, the major version has to be less than 255, from what I can gather, and I think the old format we're using is breaking the check for upgrading.

I've created a test IS project upgrading from 1.00.0000 to 2.00.0000 with no issues, so I'm thinking the issue has to be related to the format of the product version already installed.

Is there a way to use InstallScript or something to compare our old format with the new one and then do an override?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!!

**I ended up using Christopher's reply in the link he provided below (Exceeding Version Limits).  This seemed to handle the uninstallation of the existing product very well.  Thanks again Guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [ProductVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859(VS.85).aspx) property is invalid.  The SDK says:

The value of the ProductVersion property is the version of the product in string format. This property is REQUIRED.

The format of the string is as follows:

major.minor.build
The first field is the major version and has a maximum value of 255. The second field is the minor version and has a maximum value of 255. The third field is called the build version or the update version and has a maximum value of 65,535.

I also recommend reading [Exceeding Version Limits](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2010/08/wix-users-exceeding-version-limits.html).

There are hacks to work around this if you understand how FindRelatedProducts and RemoveExistingProducts works.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as if you'll need to remove or modify the ISPreventDowngrade major-upgrade item, which is what detects and prevents this kind of version downgrade (and which is usually what one wants).

(Posted follow-up to question here, too: http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=195076.)

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an older I'd like to add my two cents. 
I am creating an Installshield 2012 Spring project and I had the same issue.
Our previous installers had a Product Version in the format 2005.xx.xxxx. Obviously this 2005 was an issue.

Instead of setting the ISACTIONPROP1 property to any value (as mentioned in http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?195076-Old-Product-version-in-2009-727-1365-format).
I added a major upgrade item with the following values:

Product code of the old installers: xxx (enter yours here)
Minimum version: 2005.001.0001
Maximum version: 2005.255.65535
Version Range Inclusive (might be overkill)

With this, the system does allow the 2005.xxx.xxxx format here. It detected and removed the previous installation. For our newer installations we will use our "normal" versions:

5.008.0001
5.009.0001
...